How can I create a new TikZ-element that takes some keyval arguments?
I've got the following code:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc, spath3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (P) at (110:1.5);
  \draw[spath/save=g, thick] (200:3) -- (20:3) node[below] {$g$};
  \draw[thick] plot[mark=x, mark size=3pt] coordinates {(P)} node[above right] {$P$};
  
  \path[spath/save=CircleP] (P) circle (2);
  
  \path[name intersections={of=g and CircleP, name=g}];
  \path[spath/save=CA] (g-1) circle (4mm);
  \draw[blue] plot[mark=x, mark size=3pt] coordinates {(g-1)} node[below left] {$A$};
  \path[spath/save=CB] (g-2) circle (4mm);
  \draw[blue] plot[mark=x, mark size=3pt] coordinates {(g-2)} node[below right] {$B$};
  
  \tikzset{
    spath/split at intersections={CircleP}{CA},
    spath/split at intersections={CircleP}{CB},
    CircleP component 2/.style={blue, draw},
    CircleP component 4/.style={blue, draw},
    spath/render components=CircleP,
  }
  
  \path[spath/save=CircleA] (g-1) circle (2.3);
  \path[spath/save=CircleB] (g-2) circle (2.3);
  
  \path[name intersections={of=CircleA and CircleB, name=m}];
  \path[spath/save=CM1] (m-1) circle (4mm);
  \path[spath/save=CM2] (m-2) circle (4mm);
  
  \tikzset{
    spath/split at intersections={CircleA}{CM1},
    spath/split at intersections={CircleA}{CM2},
    CircleA component 2/.style={blue, draw},
    CircleA component 4/.style={blue, draw},
    spath/render components=CircleA,
    spath/split at intersections={CircleB}{CM1},
    spath/split at intersections={CircleB}{CM2},
    CircleB component 2/.style={blue, draw},
    CircleB component 4/.style={blue, draw},
    spath/render components=CircleB,
  }
  
  \draw[thick, blue] ($(m-1)!1.1!(m-2)$) -- ($(m-2)!1.1!(m-1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Since I use the same construction to draw the sections of a circle around the intersection point of that circle with another path, which I want to use in other tikzpictures as well, I wanted to make that part into a new TikZ-element to which I can pass the path name of the circle, the path name of the other path and the name by which the intersections schould be named.
Sure, I can always make a newcommand achieving this, but I was hoping to find another way using tikzset or something along those lines which allows for a syntax that blends in with the construction of the other elements. Also I hope that such a way would allow for an easy change of aspects like the line thickness and color.
If possible I'd like to be able to write something like
\draw circleintersect[circle=CircleA, path=g, name=g, radius=4mm];
to achive this.
I think I understood most of what was done in the answer to this question:
TikZ: Easy drawing of cuboids.
Sadly I wasn't able to get some code running for what I have in mind. My biggest problem is how to implement the keyval part I think. I tried to read the pgf/tikz manual on this but haven't gotten far.
Any help or hints are very much appreciated.

\draw circleintersect[circle=CircleA, path=g, name=g, radius=4mm]; would be much trickier to implement than, say, \draw pic [circleintersect={circle=CircleA, path=g, name=g, radius=4mm}];. that's not quite right as I've forgotten the syntax, but the point is that having pic in the path is expected - and then you can do what you want, more-or-less, whereas getting the parser to pic up an entirely new element involves more heavy lifting.

can you provide code for a single example of the construction you want to capture? as I understand it, your current example includes several examples of that construction, but I'm not sure whether I've understood correctly.

The construction I want to capture is the following:
\path[spath/save=CA] (g-1) circle (4mm);
\path[spath/save=CB] (g-2) circle (4mm);
  
\tikzset{
  spath/split at intersections={CircleP}{CA},
  spath/split at intersections={CircleP}{CB},
  CircleP component 2/.style={blue, draw},
  CircleP component 4/.style={blue, draw},
  spath/render components=CircleP,
}```
So for a given circle and path the intersections are calculated and then only the part of the circle within the specified radius is drawn.

@cfr even a pic solution would be much better than the newcommand solution I could cook up myself.

You can parametize and/or customise this further, but this should give you an idea of how to define and use a pic for this kind of construction. It isn't the only - or necessarily the best - way to do it, but it is fairly simple to implement and straightforward to extend or adapt to other constructions.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc, spath3}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/732904/
% addaswyd o gwestiwn Peter Maier: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/732895/
% goal:
% \path[name intersections={of=CircleP and g, name=g}];
% \path[spath/save=CA] (g-1) circle (4mm);
% \path[spath/save=CB] (g-2) circle (4mm);
% \tikzset{
%   spath/split at intersections={CircleP}{CA},
%   spath/split at intersections={CircleP}{CB},
%   CircleP component 2/.style={blue, draw},
%   CircleP component 4/.style={blue, draw},
%   spath/render components=CircleP,
% }
\tikzset{%
  circleintersect/.search also={/tikz,/pgf},
  circleintersect/.cd,
  error/.code={\errmessage{Ouch! Undefined!}},
  circle/.initial=circleintersect/error,
  path/.initial=circleintersect/error,
  name/.initial=MyName,
  radius/.initial=50mm,
  /tikz/.cd,
  pics/circleintersect/.style={%
    code={%
      \tikzset{%
        circleintersect/.cd,
        #1,
        /tikz/.cd,
      }%
      \path[name intersections={of/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circleintersect/path} and \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circleintersect/circle},name/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circleintersect/name}}];
      \path[spath/save=CA] ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circleintersect/path}-1}) circle (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circleintersect/radius});
      \path[spath/save=CB] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circleintersect/path}-2) circle (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circleintersect/radius});
      \tikzset{%
        spath/split at intersections/.expanded={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circleintersect/circle}}{CA},
        spath/split at intersections/.expanded={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circleintersect/circle}}{CB},
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circleintersect/circle} component 2/.style={blue, draw},
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circleintersect/circle} component 4/.style={blue, draw},
        spath/render components/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circleintersect/circle},
      }%
    }%
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (P) at (110:1.5);
  \draw[spath/save=g, thick] (200:3) -- (20:3) node[below] {$g$};
  \draw[thick] plot[mark=x, mark size=3pt] coordinates {(P)} node[above right] {$P$};

  \path[spath/save=CircleP] (P) circle (2);

  \pic {circleintersect={circle=CircleP,name=g,path=g,radius=4mm}};

  \draw[blue] plot[mark=x, mark size=3pt] coordinates {(g-1)} node[below left] {$A$};
  \draw[blue] plot[mark=x, mark size=3pt] coordinates {(g-2)} node[below right] {$B$};

  \path[spath/save=CircleA] (g-1) circle (2.3);
  \path[spath/save=CircleB] (g-2) circle (2.3);

  \path[name intersections={of=CircleA and CircleB, name=m}];
  \path[spath/save=CM1] (m-1) circle (4mm);
  \path[spath/save=CM2] (m-2) circle (4mm);

  \tikzset{
    spath/split at intersections={CircleA}{CM1},
    spath/split at intersections={CircleA}{CM2},
    CircleA component 2/.style={blue, draw},
    CircleA component 4/.style={blue, draw},
    spath/render components=CircleA,
    spath/split at intersections={CircleB}{CM1},
    spath/split at intersections={CircleB}{CM2},
    CircleB component 2/.style={blue, draw},
    CircleB component 4/.style={blue, draw},
    spath/render components=CircleB,
  }

  \draw[thick, blue] ($(m-1)!1.1!(m-2)$) -- ($(m-2)!1.1!(m-1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

The output is the same as your original code. The only difference is that the picture now uses a pic defined in the preamble, which can therefore be reused elsewhere.

Thank you very much. After changing \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circleintersect/path}-1 to \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circleintersect/name}-1 it works perfectly for the other two occurrences in my original example - I guess I should be careful to use unique names in my examples. I'm sure I'll be able to further customize it to my needs from here on.

@JeT thank you so much - I truly appreciate your saying that.
